What should be used to receiver should be used to read in fileexporter files?
I have used a collector on a remote host to collect metrics from the host. I am using the File Exporter in order to write the metrics to a file. I then need to move the file onsite so I can read it into our Observability stack. I have tried using the otlpjsonreceiver. It appears this works as long as the file is set to not compress the data. I need the compression as this will allow more of the data to be transfered and stored at the remote site. Without compress we get 15 mins of metrics in 250 M, but with compression we get 7 hours of metrics. Is there a receiver that can read in the compressed data? Using a standard zstd decompression does not seem to properly decompress the file.
My config for writing the metrics File
receivers:
  hostmetrics:
    collection_interval: 1s
    scrapers:
      disk:
      filesystem:
        metrics:
          system.filesystem.utilization:
            enabled: true
  hostmetrics/system:
    collection_interval: 30s
    scrapers:
      cpu:
        metrics:
          system.cpu.logical.count:
            enabled: true
          system.cpu.physical.count:
            enabled: true
          system.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
      load:
      memory:
        metrics:
          system.memory.limit:
            enabled: true
          system.memory.utilization:
            enabled: true
          system.linux.memory.available:
            enabled: true
      network:
      process:
        metrics:
          process.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
          process.memory.utilization:
            enabled: true
          process.disk.operations:
            enabled: true
      processes:
      paging:
        metrics:
          system.paging.utilization:
            enabled: true

processors:
  batch:
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_mib: 1000
    spike_limit_mib: 200
  resource:
    attributes:
      - key: host.id
        value: localhost
        action: insert

exporters:
  file/rotation_with_custom_settings:
    path: /scratch/tmplog/metrics.zstd
    rotation:
      max_megabytes: 250
      max_days: 30
      max_backups: 3
      localtime: false
    format: proto
    compression: zstd
  debug:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

service:
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [hostmetrics, hostmetrics/system]
      processors: [batch, resource, memory_limiter]
      exporters: [file/rotation_with_custom_settings, debug]

I attmepted to us the following config to read in the file:
receivers:
  otlpjsonfile:
    include:
      - "/tmp/log/*.zstd"

processors:
  batch:
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_mib: 1000
    spike_limit_mib: 200

exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/write"
    external_labels:
      instance: nexis_demo_ft
      node: nexis_demo_ft
      job: nexis_demo_ft
  debug:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

service:
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlpjsonfile]
      processors: [batch, memory_limiter]
      exporters: [prometheusremotewrite, debug]

but the file was never read in:
2024-04-19T18:55:11.260Z    info    fileconsumer/file.go:228    Started watching file   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlpjsonfile", "data_type": "metrics", "component": "fileconsumer", "path": "/tmp/log/metrics-2024-04-19T06-33-54.214.zstd"}

If I changed the file creation to not use compression, the otlpjsonreceiver was able to read in the file and emit to the prometheus remote write endpoint.

I think generating a file in the first place is a mistake here. Why did you decide on that approach, instead of just sending the telemetry directly to the target? I know this doesn't answer the question exactly but I'm just curious as to why you opted for this. If you have a setup with 2 collector instances one being configured as an agent, can't you just push from the agent into the main collector using OTLP directly?

@julealgon to answer your question, the reason we have to write to a file is the original collector is at a client site with no network access. We need to have them write to a file as they cannot send the data to our analytics platform directly. The second collector for reading the file in is in our network with access to send to our analytics platform. Hopefully that clarifies the issue.

Thanks Joe. How/who then fetches that file from the client network? Surely if something has access to grab the file, it should also be possible to allow access from that machine to push into the collector one? This would still centralize pushing to your analytics platform on a single collector instance. Unless you deal with some sort of manual process here.

The customer moves the file off the machine that does not have network access via a USB drive or other method and then sends the file to us from a machine that does have network access. These clients are very concerned with IP and protecting it, so as previously mentioned, the place where the services are running is Air-Gapped and does not have direct network access.

That setup is fascinating... thanks for the explanation, Joe. I'm sorry I can't help you much on this one then.
